# Handle overlapping lines in intersection of 2 lines

Tags: python, line, intersection

This python code finds the intersection for lines and I have modified it for handling colinear lines so it returns the intersection of 2 lines when they are collinear.

[image]

How to handle cases when they are overlapping in that case it should not return any point of intersection.

[image]

The output for this comes

(2,0)

But it should not return an intersection as both of the 2 lines are overlapped.

**Input**

```
line1 = ((0, 0), (2, 0))
line2 = ((1, 0), (2, 0))
```

**Code**

```
def line_intersection(line1, line2):
    x1, y1 = line1[0]
    x2, y2 = line1[1]
    x3, y3 = line2[0]
    x4, y4 = line2[1]

    # Check if the lines are collinear
    if (y2 - y1) * (x4 - x3) == (y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1):
        # Check if they have a common endpoint
        if (x1, y1) == (x3, y3) or (x1, y1) == (x4, y4) or (x2, y2) == (x3, y3) or (x2, y2) == (x4, y4):
            return (x1, y1) if (x1, y1) == (x3, y3) or (x1, y1) == (x4, y4) else (x2, y2)
        else:
            # Return "overlapping" if the lines overlap
            if max(x1, x2) >= min(x3, x4) and min(x1, x2) <= max(x3, x4) and max(y1, y2) >= min(y3, y4) and min(y1, y2) <= max(y3, y4):
                return "overlapping"
            else:
                return None

    def det(a, b):
        return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]

    xdiff = (x1 - x3, x2 - x4)
    ydiff = (y1 - y3, y2 - y4)

    div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
    if div == 0:
        return None
    d = (det((x1, y1), (x2, y2)), det((x3, y3), (x4, y4)))
    x = det(d, xdiff) / div
    y = det(d, ydiff) / div
    point = (x, y)

    # Check if the intersection point is on both lines
    if (x >= min(x1, x2) and x <= max(x1, x2)) and (y >= min(y1, y2) and y <= max(y1, y2)) and (x >= min(x3, x4) and x <= max(x3, x4)) and (y >= min(y3, y4) and y <= max(y3, y4)):
        return point
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: It is returning (2,0) in your "Check if they have a common endpoint", because the lines DO have a common endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of vector differences makes it very hard to precisely dectect colinearity or overlapping lines.

I think it would be much easier if you used the angles of the directing vectors to detect colinearity (this way is also better to avoid aprox. erors in comparisons).

```
import math

def get_angle(vector):

    #if vector lenght == 0
    if vector[0] == vector[1] == 0:
        return None

    angle = math.atan(vector[0]/vector[1]) if not vector[1] == 0 else math.pi/2 if vector[0] > 0 else -math.pi/2
    while angle < 0:
        angle = angle+(math.pi)
    return angle
    

def similar_angle(angle1, angle2):
    if angle1 == None or angle2 == None:
        return True
    return abs(angle1 - angle2) < 0.0001


x1, y1 = 0,0
x2, y2 = 1,1

x3, y3 = 0,1
x4, y4 = 1,2


#direction vectors of both lines
v12 = (x2-x1, y2-y1)
v34 = (x4-x3, y4-y3)


#angles of each vector
vs = [v12, v34]
angles = list()
for v in vs:
    angle = get_angle(v)
    angles.append(angle)


#colinearity
if abs(angles[0] - angles[1]) < 0.0001:
    print('colinear')

    condition_1 = similar_angle( get_angle( (x4-x1, y4-y1) ), get_angle( (x3-x1, y3-y1) ) )
    condition_2 = similar_angle( get_angle( (x4-x1, y4-y1) ), get_angle( (x4-x2, y4-y2) ) )

    #overlapped
    if condition_1 and condition_2:
        print('overlapped')

else:
    print('not colinear')
```